# Slick grid group all rows in pagination

Tags: jquery, arrays, slickgrid

When pagination is enabled, the slick grid considers the rows falling in that page for grouping. Is it possible to group all the rows and apply the pagination after grouping.

For eg, consider this link http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping. In that click on 50K button to populate 50K rows. It shows 50K rows and Duration 0 has some Items. Now enable paging with the page size 100. Now the Duration 0 group may have some items or may be not as it is grouping the rows in that page (Considered 1st 100 Rows)

How can use or alter SlickGrid to show Duration 0 as the first group and show all the rows with considering the pagination. Basically it should consider all the rows for grouping and aggregation and then apply pagination ?

Answer (score 3):

#### Problem description

The problem you are facing is due to the fact that the demo is not complete.

If you check out the "Group by duration & sort group by value" button `onClick` event, it calls `groupByDuration()` function which lies in `example-grouping.html` file source on line 163.

If we carefully examine this function, we can quickly determine that it lacks one thing that the button caption promises, and that is: *sorting*.

#### Proof of concept

On the demo page you have [linked](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping), follow the steps below to achieve your intended goal:

1. Click the button "50k rows".
2. Click the *Duration* header row to have the column values **sorted**.
3. Click the button "Group by duration & sort group by value".
4. Toggle the page size to 100 in the bottom right of the grid.
5. Navigate to page 9 and ascertain that this method is working.

#### Algorithmisation to a working JavaScript demo code

```
// You can skip this step if you have the large volume data already loaded
loadData(50000); 

// No other way around this, since the onSort events are handled natively in SlickGrid
$('.slick-header-columns').children().eq(2).trigger('click'); 

groupByDuration();

dataView.setPagingOptions({ pageSize: 100 }); // see results on page 9
```

---

I have also researched this problem more in depth and have found an easier way of sorting the grid.

The SlickGrid [`DataView`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView) contains a function called [`fastSort()`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js#L178) whose signature is:

> function fastSort(field, ascending)

Where the parameters you need to supply:

- field (string): the field name you want to sort, which is declared in the demo as [duration](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example-grouping.html#L116).
- ascending (boolean): determines whether the sorting order will be ascending or descending.

#### Summarizing sorting

Instead of the hackish jQuery call we have in my example code as,

```
$('.slick-header-columns').children().eq(2).trigger('click')
```

You can now use,

```
dataView.fastSort("duration", true);
```